# Spring SAML: Setting RelayState dynamically from a query parameter on the call that creates the SAML request

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I've been looking for a way to set the relaystate dynamically in the SAML request based on a value that is passed in. I noticed that the `WebSSOProfileOptions` has a relayState field but it doesn't look like there is a way to dynamically set it based on a query param passed in. Is there a way to generate the SAMLRequest with a dynamic relay state?

An example of what I am trying to accomplish

1. Browser makes a GET request to to [www.myserver.com/saml/sso?RelayState=%2Fdifferent%2Fpath](http://www.myserver.com/saml/sso?RelayState=%2Fdifferent%2Fpath)
2. The server responses with a redirect to the IdP with SAML Request AND that specific relay state that was passed in as parameters.

Comment: Can you show us which versions of spring security, opensaml etc that you are using?

Comment: `<artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>` 

and

`<artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
<version>2.6.6</version>`